# Oracle TO_NUMBER conversion fails when only fractional part is present

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, type-conversion

I have a `VARCHAR2` with a number, written as a radix point and fractional part e.g. `.02`. When using

```
TO_NUMBER(NUMBER_COLUMN)
```

I get an error

> ORA-01722: invalid number

indicating that the format is not recognized. Is there a built-in workaround (I could `DECODE` or `SUBSTR` to provide the needed zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running into this error not because of the radixpoint + fractional part present in your varchar column, rather because your varchar column contains a non-numeric character(s) present which cannot be converted into numbers when to_number runs.

I can demonstrate this via [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/afefe/7)

It [could also be that your NLS parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch3globenv.htm#i1007705) differ from what Oracle expects as a decimal separator, hence throwing this error.

You can change the character Oracle expects as a decimal operator by changing [`NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams129.htm) parameter.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ".,"
```

Will tell Oracle to expect a `.` as a decimal point and `,` as the thousands separator

Comment: I guess that Oracle expects the radix point to be ',' instead of '.'. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @ipavlic You can change the character Oracle expects to radix point to be, see my edit. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have an Oracle instance to try, but maybe using full version of TO_NUMBER would help you: TO_NUMBER(column, '9999999999D99') or TO_NUMBER(column, 'B9999999999D99')

Read more here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Also if you need to use different decimal separator then you can specify third parameter to TO_NUMBER. For example, TO_NUMBER('$94 567,00', 'L999G999D00', NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS ', ').

Comment: 'G' and 'D' are current decimal and group separators. So if there is a mismatch, it will remain. But one could provide the '9999999999.99' mask instead to make sure a dot is used.

Comment: @ipavlic There is a third parameter to TO_NUMBER where you can set decimal separator. For example, TO_NUMBER('$94 567,00', 'L999G999D00', NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS ', '). IMHO, this is a better solution.

Comment: Would you be so kind to edit your answer to include that information?